# Trigger fullscreen mode in macvim

Tags: vim, triggers, fullscreen, macvim

I'd like to set some properties when entering the fullscreen mode in MacVim automatically. E.g. toggle linenumber, set columns, etc.

Is it possible to trigger the fullscreen mode ín MacVim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no full screen [autocmd](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocommand-events).  What I've done in the past for this sort of thing is to have a `ToggleFullScreen()` function that sets things the way I want, and undoes them when I toggle again.  I typically set up a mapping for this sort of thing, or at least a command with a shorter name.

Comment: Ah, I suspected there's no better way than mapping a key to a function. I saw the "XXX" note in ```:help``` "proposing" to introduce an autocmd. Thanks for your confirmation and hint. :)